# How to make ruff to use f-string instead str.format?

Tags: python, ruff

I'm trying `ruff` but when I do `ruff check .` on my example:

```py
print("%s" % "hello")
```

it shows:

```
UP031 Use format specifiers instead of percent format
```

and if I do `ruff check . --fix` or `ruff format .` they don't change anything.

My `pyproject.toml` snipped:

```ini
[tool.ruff]
target-version = "py39"
line-length = 120
extend-select = ["E501", "UP", "RUF"]
```

Comment: Can you try `ruff check . --fix --unsafe-fixes`?

Answer (score 3):

You should always post the versions of the tools you are using and when asking for help with errors/outputs you should always post the whole output.

Running your example with ruff 0.1.2 (`ruff check .`) outputs:

```
main.py:1:7: UP031 Use format specifiers instead of percent format
Found 1 error.
No fixes available (1 hidden fix can be enabled with the `--unsafe-fixes` option).
```

The error message clearly states that there aren't fixes available unless you run the command with the option `--unsafe-fixes`. If you want ruff to fix it then you need to run the command `ruff check . --fix --unsafe-fixes`

```
$ ruff check . --fix --unsafe-fixes
Found 1 error (1 fixed, 0 remaining).
```

and it will fix the line to `print("{}".format("hello"))`

It is an unsafe fix as [explained by the documentation](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/printf-string-formatting/#known-problems), the value you are trying to print could change the way its printed if you change the formatting.

According to ruff rules ([UP032](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/f-string/#f-string-up032)) is sometimes able to fix `.format()` and turn it into an f-string, but in this case because you are directly using a string it doesn't fix it. If your code was:

```
a = "hello"
print("{}".format(a))
```

Ruff would fix it and turn it into (`ruff check . --fix):

```
a = "hello"
print(f"{a}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to understand better my problem and designed a better example.

`pyupgrade`:

```bash
cat <<EOF >|test.py
a=1
b=2
ab = "%s %s" % (a, b)
c = "%s %s"  % (ab, ab)
print("%s" % ab)
EOF
pyupgrade --py36-plus test.py
cat test.py
pyupgrade --py36-plus test.py
cat test.py

Rewriting test.py
a=1
b=2
ab = "{} {}".format(a, b)
c = "%s %s"  % (ab, ab)
print("%s" % ab)
Rewriting test.py
a=1
b=2
ab = f"{a} {b}"
c = "%s %s"  % (ab, ab)
print("%s" % ab)
```

So `pyupgrade` needs two runs and the final result is not great.

`ruff`:

```bash
cat <<EOF >|test.py
a=1
b=2
ab = "%s %s" % (a, b)
c = "%s %s"  % (ab, ab)
print("%s" % ab)
EOF
ruff check --fix --unsafe-fixes test.py
cat test.py

Found 4 errors (4 fixed, 0 remaining).
a=1
b=2
ab = f"{a} {b}"
c = f"{ab} {ab}"
print("%s" % ab)
```

`ruff` clearly does better: just one run and better results. Yet, I wonder why `print("%s" % ab)` is not converted to `print(f"{ab}").